# How to show data from get request in datatable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, rest, datatables

I have been trying to show a json response of my rest application which is a rest application using tomcat server and i am using angular in the frontend and here is my controller

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    angular.module('app')
        .controller('wfCtrl', wfCtrl);

    function wfCtrl($scope, $location, $http) {

           var table=$('#example1').DataTable(
    {
              "bServerSide": true,
                "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                    var myData = JSON.stringify(aoData);
                    $.ajax({
                        "dataType": 'json',
                        "contentType" : "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                        "type": "GET",
                        "url": "http://localhost:8080/Spring4/data/lworkflows",
                        "data": null,
                        "success": fnCallback,
                        "error": function () {
                            console.log('have some problem');
                        }
                    });
                },      
"aoColumns": [
  { "mData": null },  // for User Detail
  { "mData": "code" },
  { "mData": "label" },
  { "mData": null },
  { "mData": null },
  { "mData": null },
  { "mData": null },
]
,
"order": [[ 1, "desc" ]]});

})();
```

the request url "http://localhost:8080/Spring4/data/lworkflows" returns a json data like this

```
{"WFLIGHT":{"code":"WFLIGHT","label":"Submit the deal"},"WFCOM":{"code":"WFCOM","label":"COM"},"WFPOCTBR":{"code":"WFPOCTBR","label":"Workflow Retail POC VW"},"WFRISK":{"code":"WFRISK","label":"RISQUES"},"WFDECF":{"code":"WFDECF","label":"DECIDEUR"},"WFETUDE":{"code":"WFETUDE","label":"ETUDE"},"WFADV":{"code":"WFADV","label":"ADV"},"TEST1":{"code":"TEST1","label":"Workflow Retail POC VW"},"WFCOM2":{"code":"WFCOM2","label":"ASSCOM"}}
```

the error i am getting is

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

since my datatable cant read the data sent from the request

How can i resolve that ?

Comment: Why are you using the $.ajax in order to create a request and not the $http provided from angular ?

Comment: Also, the returned json is not an array but an object

Comment: @geo i have tried with $http too but it gives the same error

Comment: even changing the response to an array doesnt work `[{"code":"TEST1","label":"Workflow Retail POC VW"},{"code":"WFADV","label":"ADV"},{"code":"WFADV","label":"ADV"},{"code":"WFCOM","label":"COM"},{"code":"WFCOM","label":"COM"}}]`

Comment: I dont see anywhere to call the .length, so I realize that this is called from datatables code ?

Comment: The response that you wrote above as an array is not a valid json

Comment: would you like just write the valid response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148200/discussion-between-geo-and-soltani-neji).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved after converting the response to an arrays

```
var output = wfs.map(function(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).sort().map(function(key) { 
    return obj[key];
  });
```

here's the full working code

```
 function wfCtrl($scope, $location, $http) {


        $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'http://10.10.216.201:8080/Spring4/data/lworkflows'
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
          var wfs = response.data;

         var output = wfs.map(function(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).sort().map(function(key) { 
    return obj[key];
  });

});
 console.log(output);
           var table=$('#example1').DataTable(
    {
        "data":output,
  "columns": [
   { "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": '' },
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
     { "orderable": false }
  ]
,
"order": [[ 1, "desc" ]]});

        }, function errorCallback(response) {
          console.log("error");
        });

}
```